# Cleanup .net winform application on crash

Tags: .net, crash, multiple-instances

I have a c# winform client that will start a WCF service(namedpipes) on startup. If another instance is started it will contact the first instance, deliver some parameters and then exit.

If the first instance crashes (all windows close) but the process still runs, when starting a new instance it will contact the "crashed" instance and think that this is a fully working instance.

The result is that the new instance will deliver the parameters and then exit. The enduser will think that nothing happens.

I am handling for example the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` but the application is rearly shutdown because of an exception, instead a message will be shown. If the exception do however require shutdown then a gracefull exit will be done.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Hard to guess, what kind of crash closes all windows but keeps the process running?  Are you catching exceptions that you shouldn't?

Comment: Thats possible but how do I know which exceptions to catch and not catch?

Comment: Straight forward: don't catch exceptions that leave your program running without a UI.

Comment: The operating system handles it for you, it terminates the program.  Just what you need to solve your problem.

Comment: But its apparently not working in this case?